# Simple PHP hit counter / if else statement

Tags: php

I am trying to create a hit counter that once it reaches a certain number (in this case, 5), it will no longer display the amount of hits. This is my code:

```
<?php
$count = ("hits.txt");
$hits = file($count);
$hits[0] ++;
$fp = fopen($count , "w");
fputs($fp , "$hits[0]");
fclose($fp);

if ($hits > 5) {
    echo "More than 5 hits";
    }

else {
    echo $hits[0];
    }

?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. It would be much easier to do it like this:

```
$hits = file_get_contents('hits.txt');
++$hits;
file_put_contents('hits.txt', $hits);

if($hits > 5) {
    echo 'Over 5!';
}
// else etc
```

As for your current code, the problem is that you don't test the number of hits with the correct syntax `$hits[0]` -- which you already use in `fputs` -- but with the wrong `$hits` instead. Remember that due to the way [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) works, `$hits` itself is an array. PHP will happily let you compare an array to an integer, and there are [rules that define how the comparison works](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types), but don't go there.

Comment: +1 My answer shows why the initial attempt failed, but this is the proper way to handle the whole thing

Comment: That is much simpler. Thanks for your explanation and assistance.

Answer (score 3):

You need `$hits[0] > 5`:

```
if ($hits[0] > 5) {
  echo "More than 5 hits";
}
```

The array value `$hits` when compared against a number 5 is compared as the string `Array` rather than the value of the array's first item.  The string `Array` is always greater than 5.

Answer (score 0):

More or less everything. In addition to other answers this

```
fputs($fp , "$hits[0]");
```

won't work as expected, you want either `"{$hits[0]}"` or `$hits[0]` (no quotes).

That is, if you don't care about concurrent access.